# Angular 12 function returning the value before executing the statements to find media devices even after using aync await

Tags: angular, async-await, promise

```
getPermissions(name: PermissionName): Observable<PermissionState> {
    return from(
      navigator.permissions.query({ name }).then((permission: PermissionStatus) => {
        console.log(name," permission is ",permission.state);
        return permission.state;
      }),
    );
  }
```

```
getMediaPermissions = async (inputtype : any) => {
    await navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then(async devices =>     
        devices.forEach( async(device) => {
            if(device.kind == inputtype && device.label) {
              //return "present";
              console.log(inputtype);
              if(inputtype == 'videoinput'){
                //console.log("getting ",this.getPermissions("camera"));
                return await this.getPermissions("camera").toPromise();
              }
              else if(inputtype == 'audioinput'){
                return await this.getPermissions("microphone").toPromise(); 
              }
            }
            //if(device.kind == 'videoinput' && device.label) return "granted";
        }
    ))
    .catch(err => {
      return "denied";
    });
    return "denied";
  }
```

function call

```
async getMediaPermissionsCall() {
    this.subscriptions.push(
      combineLatest(
        await this.localMediaService.getMediaPermissions('videoinput'),
        await this.localMediaService.getMediaPermissions('audioinput'),
      ).subscribe(([cameraPermissions, microphonePermissions]) => {
        if (cameraPermissions === 'granted' && microphonePermissions === 'granted') {
          this.getMediaDevices();
          console.log("granted");
        } else if (cameraPermissions === 'prompt' || microphonePermissions === 'prompt') {
          navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: true }).then((stream: MediaStream) => {
            stream.getTracks().forEach((track: MediaStreamTrack) => track.stop());
            this.getMediaPermissions();
            console.log("prompt");
          });
        } else if (cameraPermissions === 'denied' || microphonePermissions === 'denied') {
          alert('Browser denied permission');
          console.log("denied");
        }
        else{
          console.log("error");
        }
      }),
    );
  }
```

console:
[image]

If I change the function call to to just check the data I am getting, I get denied as result

```
async getMediaPermissionsCall() {
    await this.localMediaService.getMediaPermissions('videoinput').then(data=>{
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
```

Output:
[image]

However, it's clear that there is no issue in checking the permission status. The problem is with the flow of the code. The service is returning "denied" without waiting for the promise. I tried few more ways, but still couldn't figure out.

Comment: You shouldn't mix Promises, async/await, and Observables. Turn your Promises into Observables using `from` or `defer`.

Comment: You're not waiting for what is happening in the `devices.forEach( async(device) => {` loop.

Comment: Do away with the `.then()` and the `forEach` and use `const devices = await navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices(); for (const device of devices) { …`